# How do you create a Button on a tkinter Canvas?

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

I created a Frame and then a Canvas.
What I want to do next is to add a Button on the Canvas.
However, when I packed the Button I cannot see the Canvas!

Here is what I tried:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, Button
from Tkinter import BOTH, W, NW, SUNKEN, TOP, X, FLAT, LEFT

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Layout Test")
        self.config(bg = '#F0F0F0')
        self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
                #create canvas
        canvas1 = Canvas(self, relief = FLAT, background = "#D2D2D2",
                                            width = 180, height = 500)
        canvas1.pack(side = TOP, anchor = NW, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        #add quit button
        button1 = Button(canvas1, text = "Quit", command = self.quit,
                                                            anchor = W)
        button1.configure(width = 10, activebackground = "#33B5E5",
                                                        relief = FLAT)
        button1.pack(side = TOP)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('800x600+10+50')
    app = Example(root)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Tkinter `pack` manager tries to resize the parent widget to the correct size to contain its child widgets, and no larger, by default. So the canvas is there - but it's precisely the same size as the button, and thus invisible.

If you want to place a widget on a canvas *without* causing the canvas to dynamically resize, you want the `Canvas.create_window()` function:

```
# ... snip ...
button1 = Button(self, text = "Quit", command = self.quit, anchor = W)
button1.configure(width = 10, activebackground = "#33B5E5", relief = FLAT)
button1_window = canvas1.create_window(10, 10, anchor=NW, window=button1)
```

This will create your button with upper-left corner at `(10, 10)` relative to the canvas, without resizing the canvas itself.

Note that you could replace the `window` argument with a reference to any other Tkinter widget. One caveat, though: the named widget must be a child of the top-level window that contains the canvas, or a child of some widget located in the same top-level window.

Answer (score 3):

you can use button1.place(x=0,y=0)  geometry manager instead of pack(side =TOP)
pack resize the master widget to makes it large enough to hold the child widget

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm#Tkinter.Pack.pack_propagate-method

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem. There isn't an official way that I know, but here's a way around it:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def clicked(event):
    print("pressed")
canvas1 = Canvas(root, relief = FLAT, background = "#D2D2D2")
canvas1.pack()
buttonBG = canvas1.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 30, fill="grey40", outline="grey60")
buttonTXT = canvas1.create_text(50, 15, text="click")
canvas1.tag_bind(buttonBG, "<Button-1>", clicked) ## when the square is clicked runs function "clicked".
canvas1.tag_bind(buttonTXT, "<Button-1>", clicked) ## same, but for the text.
root.mainloop()
```