# Image behind buttons in tkinter (PhotoImage)

Tags: python, button, tkinter, label, background-image

I've been trying to add an image so that my buttons sit on top of the image, but have only been able to make the image cover everything completely or force the image to be underneath the horizontal part the buttons cover.

Here is the relevant code for it:

```
class MainMenu(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.master.title("Adventure")
        bg = PhotoImage(file="Background-gif.gif")

        newGameButton = Button(self, text="New Game", height=2, width=20, command=self.newGame)
        newGameButton.pack(side=TOP, pady=50)
        loadGameButton = Button(self, text="Load Game", height=2, width=20, command=self.loadGame)
        loadGameButton.pack(side=TOP)
        quitButton = Button(self, text="Quit", height=2, width=20, command=self.close)
        quitButton.pack(side=TOP, pady=50)

        label = Label(self, image=bg)
        label.image = bg
        label.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.pack()
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could place an image on a canvas, and then [place a button on the canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11981214/190597):

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ImageTk

FILENAME = 'image.png'
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=250, height=250)
canvas.pack()
tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = FILENAME)
canvas.create_image(125, 125, image=tk_img)
quit_button = tk.Button(root, text = "Quit", command = root.quit, anchor = 'w',
                    width = 10, activebackground = "#33B5E5")
quit_button_window = canvas.create_window(10, 10, anchor='nw', window=quit_button)    
root.mainloop()
```

[image]