# Python 3 tkinter button over background

Tags: python, tkinter

My code creates a window with a background and a button. When you press the button, the game starts. However, the button looks weird as it is causing a grey line to cover the top of the background. How can I create a button that doesn't cause a grey line but instead shows the button over the background:

```py
from tkinter import*
import turtle
import random

master = Tk()

def code1():
    turtle.bgcolor('orange')
    h = [0]
    a = [0]
    b = [0]
    fcoord = [0,0,0]
    pos = []

    def home(x,y):
        x = 0
        y = 0
        a[0] = 0
        b[0] = 0
        h[0] = 0
        fcoord[2] = 0
        pos[:] = []
        turtle.hideturtle()
        turtle.clear()
        turtle.pu()
        turtle.color("white")
        turtle.goto(0,0)
        turtle.write("Play")
        turtle.write('')
        turtle.title("Snake")
        turtle.onscreenclick(start)
        turtle.mainloop()

    def level_1():
        turtle.clear()
        turtle.pu()
        turtle.speed(0)
        turtle.pensize(20)
        turtle.color("green")
        turtle.goto(-220,220)
        turtle.pd()
        turtle.goto(220,220)
        turtle.goto(220,-220)
        turtle.goto(-220,-220)
        turtle.goto(-220,220)
        turtle.pu()
        turtle.goto(0,0)

    def start(x,y):
        turtle.onscreenclick(None)
        level_1()
        tfood = turtle.Turtle()
        tfood.hideturtle()
        tfood.pu()
        tfood.speed(0)
        tfood.shape("circle")
        tfood.color("white")

        tscore = turtle.Turtle()
        tscore.hideturtle()
        tscore.pu()
        tscore.speed(0)
        tscore.goto(100,-250)
        tscore.write("Eats :" + str(a[0]), align="center",font=(10))

        while x > -210 and x < 210 and y > -210 and y <210:
            if fcoord[2] == 0:
                food(tfood)
                fcoord[2] = 1
            turtle.onkey(u,"Up")
            turtle.onkey(l,"Left")
            turtle.onkey(r,"Right")
            turtle.onkey(d,"Down")
            turtle.listen()
            move()
            x = turtle.xcor()
            y = turtle.ycor()       
            if x > fcoord[0]*20-5 and x < fcoord[0]*20+5 and y > fcoord[1]*20-5 and y < fcoord[1]*20+5:
                fcoord[2] = 0
                tfood.clear()
                a[0] += 1
                tscore.clear()
                tscore.write("Eats :" + str(a[0]), align="center",font=(10))

            if len(pos) > 1:
                for i in range(1,len(pos)):
                    if x < pos[i][0]+5 and x > pos[i][0]-5 and y < pos[i][1]+5 and y > pos[i][1]-5:
                            tscore.clear()
                            tfood.clear()
                            gameover()
        tscore.clear()
        tfood.clear()
        gameover()


    def food(tfood):
        x = random.randrange(-8,8,1)
        y = random.randrange(-8,8,1)
        fcoord[0] = x
        fcoord[1] = y
        tfood.hideturtle()
        tfood.pu()
        tfood.shape("circle")
        tfood.color("blue")
        tfood.goto(x*20,y*20)
        tfood.stamp()


    def u():
        if h[0] == 270:
            pass
        else:
            h[0] = 90

    def d():
        if h[0] == 90:
            pass
        else:
            h[0] = 270

    def l():
        if h[0] == 0:
            pass
        else:
            h[0] = 180

    def r():
        if h[0] == 180:
            pass
        else:
            h[0] = 0

    def move():
        turtle.pensize(10)
        turtle.color("yellow")
        turtle.pu()
        turtle.speed(3)
        turtle.setheading(h[0])
        turtle.shape("circle")
        turtle.stamp()
        turtle.fd(20)
        x = turtle.xcor()
        y = turtle.ycor()
        if b[0] > a[0]:    
            turtle.clearstamps(1)
            pos.insert(0,[round(x),round(y)])
            pos.pop(-1)
        else:
            pos.insert(0,[round(x),round(y)])      
            b[0] += 1   

    def gameover():
        turtle.onscreenclick(home)
        turtle.speed(0)
        turtle.pu()
        turtle.goto(0,150)
        turtle.color("red")
        turtle.write("Game Over",align="center", font=(10))
        turtle.goto(0,50)
        turtle.write("Score:" + str(a[0]),align="center",font=(10))
        turtle.goto(200,-200)
        turtle.write("(Click anywhere to return to the main menu)",align="right",font=(0.0000001))
        turtle.onscreenclick(home)
        turtle.mainloop()



    if __name__ == '__main__':

        home(0,0)

button = Button(master, text="Run the code", command=code1)

button.pack()

photo = PhotoImage(file = "bg.gif")

w = Label(master, image=photo)

w.pack()
ent = Entry(master)
ent.pack()
ent.focus_set()
mainloop()
```

My output show up like this:
[image]
Something is causing a grey row along the button which ruins the background. How can I make my button show up without that grey row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image behind buttons in tkinter (PhotoImage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795916/image-behind-buttons-in-tkinter-photoimage)  However, once that issue is overcome there will be problems getting this code to run a second game due to its design.

Comment: he is using import ImageTk. i get no module name ImageTk. 
I am using windows10 and idle interpeter. how can I download this module but nothing worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> he is using import ImageTk. i get no module name ImageTk.

That wasn't the relevant part of the [answer to which I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15797084/5771269).  You can continue to use tkinter's `PhotoImage()` and make this work:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(master, width=250, height=250)
canvas.pack()

photo = PhotoImage(file="bg.gif")
canvas.create_image(125, 125, image=photo)

quit_button = Button(master, text="Quit", command=master.quit, anchor='w')
quit_button_window = canvas.create_window(15, 15, anchor='nw', window=quit_button)

master.mainloop()
```

[image]

I believe `create_window()` is the bit of magic you seek.