# python tkinter: Progressbar indeterminate: mac os: how to oncrease the size of the bright area moving

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an indeterminate progress bar, the problem is when it starts running, I can barely notice that it is actually doing anything.
I noticed that the bright area is larger on the native mac os apps, or faster, so when it moves, it's noticeable.

[image: 1]

Can I modify the colours/speed of the moving part?

```
self.progressbar_Progress = ttk.Progressbar(frame_Output)
    self.progressbar_Progress.config(maximum='1', mode='indeterminate', orient='horizontal', value='0')
    self.progressbar_Progress.pack(anchor='w', expand='true', fill='x', padx='0', side='top')
self.progressbar_Progress.start()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ttk-progressbar-how-to-change-thickness-of-a-horizontal-bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912624)

Answer (score 0):

The reason the progressbar appears weirdly is because you set the start value to be 0, but then the `maximum` to be `1`. Since it only has to go 1, it will flicker because it has no distance to go.

This isn't native to Mac OS at all; it also happens on windows. To fix this, I set the `maximum` to 100.

Here is the final code:

```py
import ttkthemes as ttk

from tkinter import *

frame_Output = Tk()
p = ttk.Progressbar(frame_Output)
p.config(maximum='100', mode='indeterminate', orient='horizontal', value='0')
p.pack(anchor='w', expand='true', fill='x', padx='0', side='top')
p.start()

frame_Output.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: unfortauntely, still same result. No change at all.