# Resizing a Button in tkinter on a Mac

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm still new to `tkinter`, and noticed that when I tried to increase the size of a button using

```
 button.config(height=20, width=50)
```

It didn't work at all. It was just a huge area of white space in the violet background, and then the button in the middle of the white space. If I clicked anywhere within the white space though, it worked and did its command.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
def cheese():
    print ('hi')
logo = PhotoImage('../Desktop/logothing.gif')
explanation = """Flaming Arrows whizz over your hair, War rages around you. Suddenly,
it charges into you. A 8 foot tall mechanical beast the enemy have been training for war.
You have no chance but to fight it. You swing your sword as hard as you can...Only to
leave a minor dent on it's armor. With one blow from its club, you fall unconscious."""

w2 = Label(root, justify=LEFT, text=explanation, image = logo, 
           compound = CENTER, fg="blue", bg= "Violet", 
        font="ComicSansMS 32 bold",padx=1000, pady=1000).pack(side='left')
w1 = Button(root, text = 'Hello',command = cheese, padx=10)
w1.config(height=20, width = 50)
w1.place(x=500, y=500)
```

Comment: What platform are you running on? If a Mac, you won't be able to resize buttons due to platform restrictions. That's the price we pay for native widgets.

Comment: Yea, I'm on a mac :/ So there's no way at all to change the button size for us Mac users?

Comment: @1pokepie, I think you can check if the problem is caused by the button or by something else by removing the code for `w2`...

Comment: Nope, no way at all to change the button size on a mac. You can use a label, canvas or frame and add bindings so it works like a button. Here's an example using a canvas: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19369991/7432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested on my Mac and it seems that you cannot resize the height of the button (it works as if it was the `pady`), but just the width. In fact, if you decrease the height of your button to 1, you will have something like this:

[image]

The only workaround I can see is to increase the size of the font. 
If you use `pady`, you will just increase vertically the white box containing the button.

This might be a platform specific problem, as Bryan Oakley mentioned in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the font size doesn't work. This is what I got when I tried it because I'm experiencing the same problem.

[font going off the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ00M.png)

Comment: This is not an answer