# Tkinter not able to fill the text box to the frame using grid. Used styling to add shadow and focus

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout

***Description***

I am creating a canvas with scrollbar and adding frames with a text box in the frame and to fill the entire frame with no border. This will make it look as if the frame is the textbox. I have added shadow and styling to the frame (as coded by Bryan). This is added dynamically in for loop.

When I am trying to expand the text box to the frame, it is not expanding to fill the entire frame. There are extra spaces left.

---

***Question***

How do I fill up the entire frame with the textbox using a grid?

---

***Code***

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

focusBorderImageData = '''
    R0lGODlhQABAAPcAAHx+fMTCxKSipOTi5JSSlNTS1LSytPTy9IyKjMzKzKyq
    rOzq7JyanNza3Ly6vPz6/ISChMTGxKSmpOTm5JSWlNTW1LS2tPT29IyOjMzO
    zKyurOzu7JyenNze3Ly+vPz+/OkAKOUA5IEAEnwAAACuQACUAAFBAAB+AFYd
    QAC0AABBAAB+AIjMAuEEABINAAAAAHMgAQAAAAAAAAAAAKjSxOIEJBIIpQAA
    sRgBMO4AAJAAAHwCAHAAAAUAAJEAAHwAAP+eEP8CZ/8Aif8AAG0BDAUAAJEA
    AHwAAIXYAOfxAIESAHwAAABAMQAbMBZGMAAAIEggJQMAIAAAAAAAfqgaXESI
    5BdBEgB+AGgALGEAABYAAAAAAACsNwAEAAAMLwAAAH61MQBIAABCM8B+AAAU
    AAAAAAAApQAAsf8Brv8AlP8AQf8Afv8AzP8A1P8AQf8AfgAArAAABAAADAAA
    AACQDADjAAASAAAAAACAAADVABZBAAB+ALjMwOIEhxINUAAAANIgAOYAAIEA
    AHwAAGjSAGEEABYIAAAAAEoBB+MAAIEAAHwCACABAJsAAFAAAAAAAGjJAGGL
    AAFBFgB+AGmIAAAQAABHAAB+APQoAOE/ABIAAAAAAADQAADjAAASAAAAAPiF
    APcrABKDAAB8ABgAGO4AAJAAqXwAAHAAAAUAAJEAAHwAAP8AAP8AAP8AAP8A
    AG0pIwW3AJGSAHx8AEocI/QAAICpAHwAAAA0SABk6xaDEgB8AAD//wD//wD/
    /wD//2gAAGEAABYAAAAAAAC0/AHj5AASEgAAAAA01gBkWACDTAB8AFf43PT3
    5IASEnwAAOAYd+PuMBKQTwB8AGgAEGG35RaSEgB8AOj/NOL/ZBL/gwD/fMkc
    q4sA5UGpEn4AAIg02xBk/0eD/358fx/4iADk5QASEgAAAALnHABkAACDqQB8
    AMyINARkZA2DgwB8fBABHL0AAEUAqQAAAIAxKOMAPxIwAAAAAIScAOPxABIS
    AAAAAIIAnQwA/0IAR3cAACwAAAAAQABAAAAI/wA/CBxIsKDBgwgTKlzIsKFD
    gxceNnxAsaLFixgzUrzAsWPFCw8kDgy5EeQDkBxPolypsmXKlx1hXnS48UEH
    CwooMCDAgIJOCjx99gz6k+jQnkWR9lRgYYDJkAk/DlAgIMICZlizat3KtatX
    rAsiCNDgtCJClQkoFMgqsu3ArBkoZDgA8uDJAwk4bGDmtm9BZgcYzK078m4D
    Cgf4+l0skNkGCg3oUhR4d4GCDIoZM2ZWQMECyZQvLMggIbPmzQIyfCZ5YcME
    AwFMn/bLLIKBCRtMHljQQcDV2ZqZTRDQYfWFAwMqUJANvC8zBhUWbDi5YUAB
    Bsybt2VGoUKH3AcmdP+Im127xOcJih+oXsEDdvOLuQfIMGBD9QwBlsOnzcBD
    hfrsuVfefgzJR599A+CnH4Hb9fcfgu29x6BIBgKYYH4DTojQc/5ZGGGGGhpU
    IYIKghgiQRw+GKCEJxZIwXwWlthiQyl6KOCMLsJIIoY4LlQjhDf2mNCI9/Eo
    5IYO2sjikX+9eGCRCzL5V5JALillY07GaOSVb1G5ookzEnlhlFx+8OOXZb6V
    5Y5kcnlmckGmKaaMaZrpJZxWXjnnlmW++WGdZq5ZXQEetKmnlxPgl6eUYhJq
    KKOI0imnoNbF2ScFHQJJwW99TsBAAAVYWEAAHEQAZoi1cQDqAAeEV0EACpT/
    JqcACgRQAW6uNWCbYKcyyEwGDBgQwa2tTlBBAhYIQMFejC5AgQAWJNDABK3y
    loEDEjCgV6/aOcYBAwp4kIF6rVkXgAEc8IQZVifCBRQHGqya23HGIpsTBgSU
    OsFX/PbrVVjpYsCABA4kQCxHu11ogAQUIOAwATpBLDFQFE9sccUYS0wAxD5h
    4DACFEggbAHk3jVBA/gtTIHHEADg8sswxyzzzDQDAAEECGAQsgHiTisZResN
    gLIHBijwLQEYePzx0kw37fTSSjuMr7ZMzfcgYZUZi58DGsTKwbdgayt22GSP
    bXbYY3MggQIaONDzAJ8R9kFlQheQQAAOWGCAARrwdt23Bn8H7vfggBMueOEG
    WOBBAAkU0EB9oBGUdXIFZJBABAEEsPjmmnfO+eeeh/55BBEk0Ph/E8Q9meQq
    bbDABAN00EADFRRQ++2254777rr3jrvjFTTQwQCpz7u6QRut5/oEzA/g/PPQ
    Ry/99NIz//oGrZpUUEAAOw==
'''

borderImageData = '''
    R0lGODlhQABAAPcAAHx+fMTCxKSipOTi5JSSlNTS1LSytPTy9IyKjMzKzKyq
    rOzq7JyanNza3Ly6vPz6/ISChMTGxKSmpOTm5JSWlNTW1LS2tPT29IyOjMzO
    zKyurOzu7JyenNze3Ly+vPz+/OkAKOUA5IEAEnwAAACuQACUAAFBAAB+AFYd
    QAC0AABBAAB+AIjMAuEEABINAAAAAHMgAQAAAAAAAAAAAKjSxOIEJBIIpQAA
    sRgBMO4AAJAAAHwCAHAAAAUAAJEAAHwAAP+eEP8CZ/8Aif8AAG0BDAUAAJEA
    AHwAAIXYAOfxAIESAHwAAABAMQAbMBZGMAAAIEggJQMAIAAAAAAAfqgaXESI
    5BdBEgB+AGgALGEAABYAAAAAAACsNwAEAAAMLwAAAH61MQBIAABCM8B+AAAU
    AAAAAAAApQAAsf8Brv8AlP8AQf8Afv8AzP8A1P8AQf8AfgAArAAABAAADAAA
    AACQDADjAAASAAAAAACAAADVABZBAAB+ALjMwOIEhxINUAAAANIgAOYAAIEA
    AHwAAGjSAGEEABYIAAAAAEoBB+MAAIEAAHwCACABAJsAAFAAAAAAAGjJAGGL
    AAFBFgB+AGmIAAAQAABHAAB+APQoAOE/ABIAAAAAAADQAADjAAASAAAAAPiF
    APcrABKDAAB8ABgAGO4AAJAAqXwAAHAAAAUAAJEAAHwAAP8AAP8AAP8AAP8A
    AG0pIwW3AJGSAHx8AEocI/QAAICpAHwAAAA0SABk6xaDEgB8AAD//wD//wD/
    /wD//2gAAGEAABYAAAAAAAC0/AHj5AASEgAAAAA01gBkWACDTAB8AFf43PT3
    5IASEnwAAOAYd+PuMBKQTwB8AGgAEGG35RaSEgB8AOj/NOL/ZBL/gwD/fMkc
    q4sA5UGpEn4AAIg02xBk/0eD/358fx/4iADk5QASEgAAAALnHABkAACDqQB8
    AMyINARkZA2DgwB8fBABHL0AAEUAqQAAAIAxKOMAPxIwAAAAAIScAOPxABIS
    AAAAAIIAnQwA/0IAR3cAACwAAAAAQABAAAAI/wA/CBxIsKDBgwgTKlzIsKFD
    gxceNnxAsaLFixgzUrzAsWPFCw8kDgy5EeQDkBxPolypsmXKlx1hXnS48UEH
    CwooMCDAgIJOCjx99gz6k+jQnkWR9lRgYYDJkAk/DlAgIMICkVgHLoggQIPT
    ighVJqBQIKvZghkoZDgA8uDJAwk4bDhLd+ABBmvbjnzbgMKBuoA/bKDQgC1F
    gW8XKMgQOHABBQsMI76wIIOExo0FZIhM8sKGCQYCYA4cwcCEDSYPLOgg4Oro
    uhMEdOB84cCAChReB2ZQYcGGkxsGFGCgGzCFCh1QH5jQIW3xugwSzD4QvIIH
    4s/PUgiQYcCG4BkC5P/ObpaBhwreq18nb3Z79+8Dwo9nL9I8evjWsdOX6D59
    fPH71Xeef/kFyB93/sln4EP2Ebjegg31B5+CEDLUIH4PVqiQhOABqKFCF6qn
    34cHcfjffCQaFOJtGaZYkIkUuljQigXK+CKCE3po40A0trgjjDru+EGPI/6I
    Y4co7kikkAMBmaSNSzL5gZNSDjkghkXaaGIBHjwpY4gThJeljFt2WSWYMQpZ
    5pguUnClehS4tuMEDARQgH8FBMBBBExGwIGdAxywXAUBKHCZkAIoEEAFp33W
    QGl47ZgBAwZEwKigE1SQgAUCUDCXiwtQIIAFCTQwgaCrZeCABAzIleIGHDD/
    oIAHGUznmXABGMABT4xpmBYBHGgAKGq1ZbppThgAG8EEAW61KwYMSOBAApdy
    pNp/BkhAAQLcEqCTt+ACJW645I5rLrgEeOsTBtwiQIEElRZg61sTNBBethSw
    CwEA/Pbr778ABywwABBAgAAG7xpAq6mGUUTdAPZ6YIACsRKAAbvtZqzxxhxn
    jDG3ybbKFHf36ZVYpuE5oIGhHMTqcqswvyxzzDS/HDMHEiiggQMLDxCZXh8k
    BnEBCQTggAUGGKCB0ktr0PTTTEfttNRQT22ABR4EkEABDXgnGUEn31ZABglE
    EEAAWaeN9tpqt832221HEEECW6M3wc+Hga3SBgtMODBABw00UEEBgxdO+OGG
    J4744oZzXUEDHQxwN7F5G7QRdXxPoPkAnHfu+eeghw665n1vIKhJBQUEADs=
'''

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style()
borderImage = tk.PhotoImage("borderImage", data=borderImageData)
focusBorderImage = tk.PhotoImage("focusBorderImage", data=focusBorderImageData)

style.element_create("RoundedFrame",
                     "image", borderImage,
                     ("focus", focusBorderImage),
                     border=16, sticky="nsew")
style.layout("RoundedFrame",
             [("RoundedFrame", {"sticky": "nsew"})])
root.configure(background="white")
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
scroll = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient='horizontal', command=canvas.xview)
canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=scroll.set)
frame = tk.Frame(canvas) # frame does not get pack() as it needs to be embedded into canvas throught canvas.
scroll.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
canvas.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor='nw')
frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda x: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))) # lambda function

for i in range(5):
    frame1 = ttk.Frame(frame, style="RoundedFrame", padding=10)
    journal1 = tk.Text(frame1, borderwidth=2, highlightthickness=0,  width = 40, height = 38)
#        journal1.configure(borderwidth="3")
    journal1.configure(relief="groove")
    journal1.configure(background="white")
    journal1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(100, 10), sticky = 'nswe') # grid instead
    journal1.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event: frame.state(["focus"]))
    journal1.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda event: frame.state(["!focus"]))
    frame1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame1.grid(row=0,column=i, sticky = 'nswe')


root.mainloop()
```

---

***Output***

[image]

Comment: You need to give a weight to the row and column that you're placing the text widget in. `pack` is much easier to use when you just have one child in a parent.

Comment: @Bryan: I added weight in the for loop. frame1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
I want the textbox to be placed side by side, hence i used a for loop with i variable as the column for the grid.

Comment: @BryanOakley: I used the .pack(fill = "both", expand = True) method, still the textbox did not fit the frame.

Comment: Found the solution. I just packed the frame to the root but not the textbox to the frame. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had troubles with the focus of the frame, it complained `frame has no attribute 'state'`. It works in [Bryans original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51426557/9938317). I fixed it with closures.

```
def frameFocusCreator(frame, focusState):
    def changeState(event):
        frame.state([focusState])
    return changeState
for i in range(5):
    frame1 = ttk.Frame(frame, style="RoundedFrame", padding=10)
    journal1 = tk.Text(frame1, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,  width = 40, height = 38)
    journal1.configure(relief="groove")
    journal1.configure(background="white")
    journal1.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    journal1.bind("<FocusIn>", frameFocusCreator(frame1, "focus"))
    journal1.bind("<FocusOut>", frameFocusCreator(frame1, "!focus"))
    frame1.grid(row=0,column=i, sticky = 'nswe')
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.