# How to custom button and text box using Python GUI?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to ask how to make a custom button and custom text box by using Python?

1. A custom button should has: transparent feature with only border, round corner, shadow feature, icon need to be placed, animate feature like color changed when click and hover on it.
2. A custom text box should has: no border but only underline, round corner,  transparent feature, icon need to be placed, animate feature like underline becomes thicker when click on it.

Below is my code:

```
frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#000000', bd=0)
frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.1, anchor='n')

entry = tk.Entry(frame, font=60, relief='flat')
entry.place(relwidth=0.65, relheight=1)

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Run", relief='flat', font=40, command=lambda: get_weather(entry.get()))
button.place(relx=0.7, relheight=1, relwidth=0.3)
```

Here is the reference image design that I prefer:
[image: screen]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You sure you want to do this in built-in tkinter? You can explore pyQt5 it has a frontend editor/designer, where you can customize the entire picture then code what each part/button/widget does in python.

Comment: @Joe, hi, thanks for your quick reply, I actually done writing a program by using Python, the problem is it has no GUI. Every time I want to run the program, i need to open 'Sublime Text' or 'Python IDLE' to run it, so I was thinking of creating a GUI for my Python program. Besides using pyQt5, does it possible creates GUI using C# and link to my Python program?

Comment: I feel you man, got a lot of projects like that. I actually created my own desktop app using tkinter for one particular project that I used to run in console. I can say that though a little bit more friendly than in other languages, tkinter proves to be a little hard to use. Specifically in creating a sophisticated design/frontend and also limitations on design options. If you don't mind your app looking like a windows 98 program tkinter will be fine. As far as your problem here goes, there are options you might want to explore in [ttk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html)

Comment: Ya, tkinter is a little bit hard to use, it is not like Javascript or CSS or C#. I actually kind of mind to my app looking like a windows 98 program, hahaha, that is why I am looking for other option to create GUI rather than using tkinter.

Comment: For the ui design you showed here, C# is the way to go I think hehe! I'm not particularly great at tkinter however, so maybe someone has ideas on how to achieve that ui using tkinter, good luck man happy coding.

Comment: Oh I see, ok, I got it, my last question, does it possible to link C# with Python? Any method could you mind to share with me?

Comment: same question "does it possible to link C# with Python?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tkinter comes with the module `ttk` which stands for *themed tk*. It provides a way to create widget themes.

How to do it is under-documented, but [tkdocs.com](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html) has a good discussion of the fundamentals.

At the end of this question is code which can create frames that have rounded corners, a shadow, and a unique color to represent focus, to serve as an example of what you can do.  Answering all your questions is a bit beyond the scope of what stackoverflow is for, but hopefully, this is enough to show that what you want is possible.

[image: screenshot]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

focusBorderImageData = '''
    R0lGODlhQABAAPcAAHx+fMTCxKSipOTi5JSSlNTS1LSytPTy9IyKjMzKzKyq
    rOzq7JyanNza3Ly6vPz6/ISChMTGxKSmpOTm5JSWlNTW1LS2tPT29IyOjMzO
    zKyurOzu7JyenNze3Ly+vPz+/OkAKOUA5IEAEnwAAACuQACUAAFBAAB+AFYd
    QAC0AABBAAB+AIjMAuEEABINAAAAAHMgAQAAAAAAAAAAAKjSxOIEJBIIpQAA
    sRgBMO4AAJAAAHwCAHAAAAUAAJEAAHwAAP+eEP8CZ/8Aif8AAG0BDAUAAJEA
    AHwAAIXYAOfxAIESAHwAAABAMQAbMBZGMAAAIEggJQMAIAAAAAAAfqgaXESI
    5BdBEgB+AGgALGEAABYAAAAAAACsNwAEAAAMLwAAAH61MQBIAABCM8B+AAAU
    AAAAAAAApQAAsf8Brv8AlP8AQf8Afv8AzP8A1P8AQf8AfgAArAAABAAADAAA
    AACQDADjAAASAAAAAACAAADVABZBAAB+ALjMwOIEhxINUAAAANIgAOYAAIEA
    AHwAAGjSAGEEABYIAAAAAEoBB+MAAIEAAHwCACABAJsAAFAAAAAAAGjJAGGL
    AAFBFgB+AGmIAAAQAABHAAB+APQoAOE/ABIAAAAAAADQAADjAAASAAAAAPiF
    APcrABKDAAB8ABgAGO4AAJAAqXwAAHAAAAUAAJEAAHwAAP8AAP8AAP8AAP8A
    AG0pIwW3AJGSAHx8AEocI/QAAICpAHwAAAA0SABk6xaDEgB8AAD//wD//wD/
    /wD//2gAAGEAABYAAAAAAAC0/AHj5AASEgAAAAA01gBkWACDTAB8AFf43PT3
    5IASEnwAAOAYd+PuMBKQTwB8AGgAEGG35RaSEgB8AOj/NOL/ZBL/gwD/fMkc
    q4sA5UGpEn4AAIg02xBk/0eD/358fx/4iADk5QASEgAAAALnHABkAACDqQB8
    AMyINARkZA2DgwB8fBABHL0AAEUAqQAAAIAxKOMAPxIwAAAAAIScAOPxABIS
    AAAAAIIAnQwA/0IAR3cAACwAAAAAQABAAAAI/wA/CBxIsKDBgwgTKlzIsKFD
    gxceNnxAsaLFixgzUrzAsWPFCw8kDgy5EeQDkBxPolypsmXKlx1hXnS48UEH
    CwooMCDAgIJOCjx99gz6k+jQnkWR9lRgYYDJkAk/DlAgIMICZlizat3KtatX
    rAsiCNDgtCJClQkoFMgqsu3ArBkoZDgA8uDJAwk4bGDmtm9BZgcYzK078m4D
    Cgf4+l0skNkGCg3oUhR4d4GCDIoZM2ZWQMECyZQvLMggIbPmzQIyfCZ5YcME
    AwFMn/bLLIKBCRtMHljQQcDV2ZqZTRDQYfWFAwMqUJANvC8zBhUWbDi5YUAB
    Bsybt2VGoUKH3AcmdP+Im127xOcJih+oXsEDdvOLuQfIMGBD9QwBlsOnzcBD
    hfrsuVfefgzJR599A+CnH4Hb9fcfgu29x6BIBgKYYH4DTojQc/5ZGGGGGhpU
    IYIKghgiQRw+GKCEJxZIwXwWlthiQyl6KOCMLsJIIoY4LlQjhDf2mNCI9/Eo
    5IYO2sjikX+9eGCRCzL5V5JALillY07GaOSVb1G5ookzEnlhlFx+8OOXZb6V
    5Y5kcnlmckGmKaaMaZrpJZxWXjnnlmW++WGdZq5ZXQEetKmnlxPgl6eUYhJq
    KKOI0imnoNbF2ScFHQJJwW99TsBAAAVYWEAAHEQAZoi1cQDqAAeEV0EACpT/
    JqcACgRQAW6uNWCbYKcyyEwGDBgQwa2tTlBBAhYIQMFejC5AgQAWJNDABK3y
    loEDEjCgV6/aOcYBAwp4kIF6rVkXgAEc8IQZVifCBRQHGqya23HGIpsTBgSU
    OsFX/PbrVVjpYsCABA4kQCxHu11ogAQUIOAwATpBLDFQFE9sccUYS0wAxD5h
    4DACFEggbAHk3jVBA/gtTIHHEADg8sswxyzzzDQDAAEECGAQsgHiTisZResN
    gLIHBijwLQEYePzx0kw37fTSSjuMr7ZMzfcgYZUZi58DGsTKwbdgayt22GSP
    bXbYY3MggQIaONDzAJ8R9kFlQheQQAAOWGCAARrwdt23Bn8H7vfggBMueOEG
    WOBBAAkU0EB9oBGUdXIFZJBABAEEsPjmmnfO+eeeh/55BBEk0Ph/E8Q9meQq
    bbDABAN00EADFRRQ++2254777rr3jrvjFTTQwQCpz7u6QRut5/oEzA/g/PPQ
    Ry/99NIz//oGrZpUUEAAOw==
'''

borderImageData = '''
    R0lGODlhQABAAPcAAHx+fMTCxKSipOTi5JSSlNTS1LSytPTy9IyKjMzKzKyq
    rOzq7JyanNza3Ly6vPz6/ISChMTGxKSmpOTm5JSWlNTW1LS2tPT29IyOjMzO
    zKyurOzu7JyenNze3Ly+vPz+/OkAKOUA5IEAEnwAAACuQACUAAFBAAB+AFYd
    QAC0AABBAAB+AIjMAuEEABINAAAAAHMgAQAAAAAAAAAAAKjSxOIEJBIIpQAA
    sRgBMO4AAJAAAHwCAHAAAAUAAJEAAHwAAP+eEP8CZ/8Aif8AAG0BDAUAAJEA
    AHwAAIXYAOfxAIESAHwAAABAMQAbMBZGMAAAIEggJQMAIAAAAAAAfqgaXESI
    5BdBEgB+AGgALGEAABYAAAAAAACsNwAEAAAMLwAAAH61MQBIAABCM8B+AAAU
    AAAAAAAApQAAsf8Brv8AlP8AQf8Afv8AzP8A1P8AQf8AfgAArAAABAAADAAA
    AACQDADjAAASAAAAAACAAADVABZBAAB+ALjMwOIEhxINUAAAANIgAOYAAIEA
    AHwAAGjSAGEEABYIAAAAAEoBB+MAAIEAAHwCACABAJsAAFAAAAAAAGjJAGGL
    AAFBFgB+AGmIAAAQAABHAAB+APQoAOE/ABIAAAAAAADQAADjAAASAAAAAPiF
    APcrABKDAAB8ABgAGO4AAJAAqXwAAHAAAAUAAJEAAHwAAP8AAP8AAP8AAP8A
    AG0pIwW3AJGSAHx8AEocI/QAAICpAHwAAAA0SABk6xaDEgB8AAD//wD//wD/
    /wD//2gAAGEAABYAAAAAAAC0/AHj5AASEgAAAAA01gBkWACDTAB8AFf43PT3
    5IASEnwAAOAYd+PuMBKQTwB8AGgAEGG35RaSEgB8AOj/NOL/ZBL/gwD/fMkc
    q4sA5UGpEn4AAIg02xBk/0eD/358fx/4iADk5QASEgAAAALnHABkAACDqQB8
    AMyINARkZA2DgwB8fBABHL0AAEUAqQAAAIAxKOMAPxIwAAAAAIScAOPxABIS
    AAAAAIIAnQwA/0IAR3cAACwAAAAAQABAAAAI/wA/CBxIsKDBgwgTKlzIsKFD
    gxceNnxAsaLFixgzUrzAsWPFCw8kDgy5EeQDkBxPolypsmXKlx1hXnS48UEH
    CwooMCDAgIJOCjx99gz6k+jQnkWR9lRgYYDJkAk/DlAgIMICkVgHLoggQIPT
    ighVJqBQIKvZghkoZDgA8uDJAwk4bDhLd+ABBmvbjnzbgMKBuoA/bKDQgC1F
    gW8XKMgQOHABBQsMI76wIIOExo0FZIhM8sKGCQYCYA4cwcCEDSYPLOgg4Oro
    uhMEdOB84cCAChReB2ZQYcGGkxsGFGCgGzCFCh1QH5jQIW3xugwSzD4QvIIH
    4s/PUgiQYcCG4BkC5P/ObpaBhwreq18nb3Z79+8Dwo9nL9I8evjWsdOX6D59
    fPH71Xeef/kFyB93/sln4EP2Ebjegg31B5+CEDLUIH4PVqiQhOABqKFCF6qn
    34cHcfjffCQaFOJtGaZYkIkUuljQigXK+CKCE3po40A0trgjjDru+EGPI/6I
    Y4co7kikkAMBmaSNSzL5gZNSDjkghkXaaGIBHjwpY4gThJeljFt2WSWYMQpZ
    5pguUnClehS4tuMEDARQgH8FBMBBBExGwIGdAxywXAUBKHCZkAIoEEAFp33W
    QGl47ZgBAwZEwKigE1SQgAUCUDCXiwtQIIAFCTQwgaCrZeCABAzIleIGHDD/
    oIAHGUznmXABGMABT4xpmBYBHGgAKGq1ZbppThgAG8EEAW61KwYMSOBAApdy
    pNp/BkhAAQLcEqCTt+ACJW645I5rLrgEeOsTBtwiQIEElRZg61sTNBBethSw
    CwEA/Pbr778ABywwABBAgAAG7xpAq6mGUUTdAPZ6YIACsRKAAbvtZqzxxhxn
    jDG3ybbKFHf36ZVYpuE5oIGhHMTqcqswvyxzzDS/HDMHEiiggQMLDxCZXh8k
    BnEBCQTggAUGGKCB0ktr0PTTTEfttNRQT22ABR4EkEABDXgnGUEn31ZABglE
    EEAAWaeN9tpqt832221HEEECW6M3wc+Hga3SBgtMODBABw00UEEBgxdO+OGG
    J4744oZzXUEDHQxwN7F5G7QRdXxPoPkAnHfu+eeghw665n1vIKhJBQUEADs=
'''

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style()
borderImage = tk.PhotoImage("borderImage", data=borderImageData)
focusBorderImage = tk.PhotoImage("focusBorderImage", data=focusBorderImageData)

style.element_create("RoundedFrame",
                     "image", borderImage,
                     ("focus", focusBorderImage),
                     border=16, sticky="nsew")
style.layout("RoundedFrame",
             [("RoundedFrame", {"sticky": "nsew"})])

frame1 = ttk.Frame(style="RoundedFrame", padding=10)
text1 = tk.Text(frame1, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, wrap="word",
                width=40, height=4)
text1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

text1.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event: frame1.state(["focus"]))
text1.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda event: frame1.state(["!focus"]))
text1.insert("end", "This widget has the focus")

frame2 = ttk.Frame(style="RoundedFrame", padding=10)
text2 = tk.Text(frame2, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, wrap="word",
                width=40, height=4)
text2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
text2.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event: frame2.state(["focus"]))
text2.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda event: frame2.state(["!focus"]))
text2.insert("end", "This widget does not have the focus")

root.configure(background="white")
frame1.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)
frame2.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)

frame1.focus_set()

root.mainloop()
```

---

This code was originally posted as an answer to the question [Tkinter: How to make a rounded corner text widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51425633/7432). The [original version of this code](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/ttk+Frame+with+Custom+Borders) was written in Tcl in 2007, before stackoverflow existed.

Comment: Wow, that is great! Thanks a lot, man! However, I was wondering that what if I use C# to create GUI instead of tkinter? I already done writing a Python program, does it possible to link C# with Python?