# round corner for a frame tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter, frame, rounded-corners

How to create a round corner for a frame  or a canvas in python?
for set border radius of frame or a canvas?

```py
frame = Canvas(master, width=100, height=34)
```

Comment: Read up on [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) and pick one from [`[tkinter] round corner`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%5Btkinter%5D+round+corner)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow community. Whenever you post a question please do some prior research before asking a question, and list it in the question of what all you have tried. Its better for the whole community

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: How to make a rounded corner text widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51425633/tkinter-how-to-make-a-rounded-corner-text-widget)