# Creating Rounded Edges for a Polygon in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, tkinter-canvas

I came across this interesting question ([How to make a tkinter canvas rectangle with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44099594/how-to-make-a-tkinter-canvas-rectangle-with-rounded-corners/61162928#61162928)) related to creating rounded rectangles in Tkinter and specifically, this answer by Francisco Gomes (modified a bit):

```
def roundPolygon(x, y, sharpness):

    # The sharpness here is just how close the sub-points
    # are going to be to the vertex. The more the sharpness,
    # the more the sub-points will be closer to the vertex.
    # (This is not normalized)
    if sharpness < 2:
        sharpness = 2

    ratioMultiplier = sharpness - 1
    ratioDividend = sharpness

    # Array to store the points
    points = []

    # Iterate over the x points
    for i in range(len(x)):
        # Set vertex
        points.append(x[i])
        points.append(y[i])

        # If it's not the last point
        if i != (len(x) - 1):
            # Insert submultiples points. The more the sharpness, the more these points will be
            # closer to the vertex. 
            points.append((ratioMultiplier*x[i] + x[i + 1])/ratioDividend)
            points.append((ratioMultiplier*y[i] + y[i + 1])/ratioDividend)
            points.append((ratioMultiplier*x[i + 1] + x[i])/ratioDividend)
            points.append((ratioMultiplier*y[i + 1] + y[i])/ratioDividend)
        else:
            # Insert submultiples points.
            points.append((ratioMultiplier*x[i] + x[0])/ratioDividend)
            points.append((ratioMultiplier*y[i] + y[0])/ratioDividend)
            points.append((ratioMultiplier*x[0] + x[i])/ratioDividend)
            points.append((ratioMultiplier*y[0] + y[i])/ratioDividend)
            # Close the polygon
            points.append(x[0])
            points.append(y[0])
```

When I adapted this code to work with my graphics library, it worked well enough! but when I create a 'stretched-square' (a non-square rectangle), the roundness becomes stretched too:

[image]

So how can I change this code to remove the stretched roundness and keep it a constant radius?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one approach that uses the built in `tcl tk` primitives `canvas.create_line`, and `canvas.create_arc` to build rectangles of various sizes, and proportions with round corners (arc of a circle).

The corners radii is expressed as a proportion of the shortest side of the rectangle `(0.0 --> 0.5)`, and can be parametrized.

The function `make_round_corners_rect` returns a tuple containing all `canvas item ids` as fragments of the rectangle entity. All fragments are tagged with their companions' ids, so accessing the entire object is possible with only one fragment id.

---

[image]

---

```
#! python3

import math
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import TclError


def make_round_corners_rect(canvas, x0, y0, x1, y1, ratio=0.2, npts=12):

    if x0 > x1:
        x0, x1 = x1, x0
    if y0 > y1:
        y0, y1 = y1, y0
        
    r = min(x1 - x0, y1 - y0) * ratio
    
    items = []

    topleft = x0, y0
    tld = x0, y0 + r
    tlr = x0 + r, y0
    item = canvas.create_arc(x0, y0, x0+2*r, y0+2*r, start=90, extent=90, fill='', outline='black', style=tk.ARC)
    items.append(item)
    
    top_right = x1, y0
    trl = x1 - r, y0
    trd = x1, y0 + r
    item = canvas.create_line(*tlr, *trl, fill='black')
    items.append(item)
    item = canvas.create_arc(x1-2*r, y0, x1, y0+2*r, start=0, extent=90, fill='', outline='black', style=tk.ARC)
    items.append(item)

    bot_right = x1, y1
    bru = x1, y1 - r
    brl = x1 - r, y1
    item = canvas.create_line(*trd, *bru, fill='black')
    items.append(item)
    item = canvas.create_arc(x1-2*r, y1-2*r, x1, y1, start=270, extent=90, fill='', outline='black', style=tk.ARC)
    items.append(item)

    bot_left = x0, y1
    blr = x0 + r, y1
    blu = x0, y1 - r
    item = canvas.create_line(*brl, *blr, fill='black')
    items.append(item)
    item = canvas.create_arc(x0, y1-2*r, x0+2*r, y1, start=180, extent=90, fill='', outline='black', style=tk.ARC)
    items.append(item)
    item = canvas.create_line(*blu, *tld, fill='black')
    items.append(item)
    
    items = tuple(items)
    print(items)
    
    for item_ in items:
        for _item in items:
            canvas.addtag_withtag(item_, _item)

    return items


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
    canvas.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

    TL = 100, 100
    BR = 400, 200
    make_round_corners_rect(canvas, *TL, *BR)
    
    TL = 100, 300
    BR = 400, 400
    make_round_corners_rect(canvas, *TL, *BR, ratio = .3)

    TL = 300, 50
    BR = 350, 450
    that_rect = make_round_corners_rect(canvas, *TL, *BR, ratio=.4)
    for fragment in that_rect:
        canvas.itemconfig(fragment, width=4)
        try:
            canvas.itemconfig(fragment, outline='blue')
        except TclError:
            canvas.itemconfig(fragment, fill='blue')

    
    TL = 150, 50
    BR = 200, 450
    make_round_corners_rect(canvas, *TL, *BR, ratio=.07)
    
    TL = 30, 30
    BR = 470, 470
    that_rect = make_round_corners_rect(canvas, *TL, *BR, ratio=.3)
    for fragment in that_rect:
        canvas.itemconfig(fragment, dash=(3, 3))
   
    TL = 20, 20
    BR = 480, 480
    make_round_corners_rect(canvas, *TL, *BR, ratio=.1)
    

    root.mainloop()
```

---

The next step, (*left to the reader as an exercise*), is to encapsulate the round rectangles in a class.

---

### Edit: how to fill a rounded corners rectangle:

It is a bit involved, and in the long run, probably requires an approach where all points are explicitly defined, and the shape is formed as a polygon, instead of the aggregation of `tkinter` primitives. In this edit, the rounded corners rectangle is filled with two overlapping rectangles, and four disks; it allows to create a filled/unfilled shape, but not to change that property after creation - although it would not require too much work to be able to do this too. (collecting the canvas ids, and turning them on/off on demand, in conjunction with the `outline` property); however, as mentioned earlier, this would make more sense to encapsulate all this behavior in a class that mimicks the behavior of `tk.canvas.items`.

```
def make_round_corners_rect(canvas, x0, y0, x1, y1, ratio=0.2, npts=12, filled=False, fillcolor=''):
    ...
    if filled:
        canvas.create_rectangle(x0+r, y0, x1-r, y1, fill=fillcolor, outline='')
        canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0+r, x1, y1-r, fill=fillcolor, outline='')
        canvas.create_oval(x0, y0, x0+2*r, y0+2*r, fill=fillcolor, outline='')
        canvas.create_oval(x1-2*r, y0, x1, y0+2*r, fill=fillcolor, outline='')
        canvas.create_oval(x1-2*r, y1-2*r, x1, y1, fill=fillcolor, outline='')
        canvas.create_oval(x0, y1-2*r, x0+2*r, y1, fill=fillcolor, outline='')
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
    TL = 100, 300
    BR = 400, 400
    make_round_corners_rect(canvas, *TL, *BR, ratio=.3, filled=True, fillcolor='cyan')
    ...
```

---

[image]

---

Comment: Thank you! Now I'll probably be able to generalize this for any polygon. And about encapsulating this in a class - this is what I've been working on. Tkinter I wld say has a steep learning curve, so, for the past 2 years (on & off) I've tried creating a library built on top of Tk to make everything easier. https://github.com/BhavyeMathur/goopy if you want to take a look at it) :)

Comment: You are welcome, Glad I could help. I had a look at your lib, it is an ambitious project; you indeed put a lot of work into it. Maybe you would gain by setting priorities and tightening the focus of where you want to take it?

Comment: Yes indeed. I've been trying to get together a To-Do list and my main priority right now is to test what I've already done. While developing it for use in my own projects, I never bothered to test parts of it I wasn't using so there are a lot of bugs. For the future though, I just want it to be something that people could use to make non-graphic heavy 2D games and applications.

Comment: Related to this question, how would I fill the rounded rectangle with a specific colour?

Comment: It is a bit involved, and in the long run, probably requires an approach where all points are explicitly defined, and the shape is formed as a polygon. I posted an edit where the rectangle is filled with two overlapping rectangles, and four disks; it allows to createa filled/unfilled shape, but not to change that property after creation - although it would not require too much work to be able to do this too.