# Make a Tkinter GUI have rounded corners

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I make a Tkinter GUI have rounded corners?
Example:[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a tkinter canvas rectangle with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44099594/how-to-make-a-tkinter-canvas-rectangle-with-rounded-corners)

Comment: Tkinter  has no ability to do this if by "Tkinter GUI" you're referring to the root and toplevel windows. You'll have to try to fine something specific to the platform you're building on.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the window itself, I am afraid that is not possible due to the fact that Tkinter needs to be supported by 3 different operating systems, all with different window handlers. If you wish to attempt to do this, you will need to find a OS-specific library to do this. If you mean having a `canvas` with a rounded rectangle inside it, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44099594/how-to-make-a-tkinter-canvas-rectangle-with-rounded-corners) question, which jezza_99 mentioned, covers this quite nicely.