# How can I change the shape of a label?

Tags: python, tkinter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1EpP.png)
How can I change the tips to rounded?

I want it to be like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noXVL.png)

Is there any function?

I want no points to appear on my label

Comment: You simply cannot do this with a Label, or any other Tkinter widget - they're inherently rectangles.  The only possibility would be to draw everything yourself, on a Canvas - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44099594/how-to-make-a-tkinter-canvas-rectangle-with-rounded-corners for details.

Comment: https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter