# How to create a button inside of a a Tk canvas in python 3.7

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I was wondering how to put a button inside of a canvas using the tkinter module.  This question was asked, but it was 5 years ago and for a different version so It was not very convenient for my situation and I am still a beginner so I only understood about 3/4 of the code in the best answer. Here is the question: [How to make a Button using the tkinter Canvas widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369391/how-to-make-a-button-using-the-tkinter-canvas-widget)

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
c=Canvas(root,width=200,height=150,bg='blue')
c.pack(side = 'top')

c.create_text(100,50,anchor='c',fill='orange',font='Times 28',text='List')

button = Button(root, text="Quit",command=root.destroy)
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

When I run this code it creates the button below my Canvas and not on the Canvas.  I looked for help on https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/tkinter.html the guide for the IDE I am using.  I could not find a way to put the button on the Canvas even though I may or may not have missed something.  If this question is seen as not helpful or unnecessary I apologize and will close it immediately.

**Version of Python:** 3.7

**Level:** Beginner

**Running Code on:** IDLE 64-bit

**OS:** Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `pack()` tkinter will place the button on it's master (root), and the area where the canvas is drawn is already occupied.

To place the button on the canvas you should use the function `create_window()` on the canvas:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root,width=200,height=150,bg='blue')
c.pack(side = 'top')

c.create_text(100, 50, anchor='c', fill='orange', font='Times 28', text='List')

button = Button(root, text="Quit", command=root.destroy)
canvas_widget = c.create_window(100, 100, window=button)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

delete button.pack()

try use the code below

button = Button(root, text="Quit", command=root.destroy)

c.create_window(10, 10, anchor=NW, window=button)