# How to draw diagonal arrows in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I need to draw two arrows from the blue and green box pointing to the yellow box. I tried drawing diagonal lines using create_line but it didn't work. can anyone please suggest any ways I could draw these arrows. 
the error message when using create_line is: AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'create_line'

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


window = Tk()
window.geometry("900x500")
window.configure(background='red')
window.title("Theoretical")

label1 = Label(window, text="Hess' cycle of combustion", fg="black", bg="red", font=("Comic Sans MS", 20))
label1.pack()    

text1 = Text(window, width=20, height = 1, bg= "blue")
text1.place(x=200, y=100)

window.create_line(0, 0, 200, 100)
window.create_line(0, 100, 200, 0, fill="white")

text2 = Text(window, width=20, height = 1, bg= "green")
text2.place(x=520, y=100)

text3 = Text(window, width=20, height = 1, bg= "yellow")
text3.place(x=370, y=250)

##    arrow = Label(window, width=13,height = 1, text = "-------------->", bg= "lawn green", font=("Helvetica", 20))
##    arrow.place(x= 330, y=90)

global textbox
textbox = Text(window, width=400, height=10)
textbox.place(x=0, y= 365)
```

Comment: Please explain _and_ provide how exactly the Canvas method has failed.

Comment: `create_line` is a method on a canvas. I don't see a canvas in your code.

Comment: In `tkinter`, `Canvas` line objects have an `arrowhead` option that you might be able to use. Here's some [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_line.html).

Comment: i added the error message when i added create_line which was AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'create_line'

Answer (score 12):

tkinter lines have an `arrow` option; however, as pointed out in te comments,`create_line` is a `Canvas` method: you must therefore use a `tk.Canvas` object to draw lines:

This minimum example shows you how:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(window)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_line(0, 0, 200, 100, arrow=tk.LAST)

window.mainloop()
```

[image]

Please note that to avoid "hard to fix" problems and unexpected behavior, it is usually recommended not to import modules in the main namespace (i/e do not `from tkinter import *`), and not to mix geometry managers ((i/e do not use `.place` and `.pack` in the same app)

### Edit:

In order to place widgets on a canvas, you must [use the `Canvas.create_window()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980812/how-do-you-create-a-button-on-a-tkinter-canvas):

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("600x600")

canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=600, height=600)

label_1 = tk.Label(window, text = "from here", anchor = tk.W)
label_1.configure(width = 10, activebackground = "#33B5E5", relief = tk.FLAT)
label_1_window = canvas.create_window(280, 0, anchor=tk.NW, window=label_1)

label_2 = tk.Label(window, text = "to there", anchor = tk.W)
label_2.configure(width = 10, activebackground = "#33B5E5", relief = tk.FLAT)
label_2_window = canvas.create_window(280, 310, anchor=tk.NW, window=label_2)

canvas.pack()
canvas.create_line(300, 40, 300, 300, arrow=tk.LAST)


window.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you... but i am still not sure how to include it in my program. do i create this window within my window?

Comment: @tamilini Replace your `....create_line(...)` lines with the lines above that starts with `canvas...`.